# SWIFT - Como alimentar uma TableView com informações de um NSArray?

Tags: json, swift

```
var nomes:NSArray = []    
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()    

      Alamofire.request(.GET, MyUrl,parameters: nil,encoding: .JSON).response { (_, _, data, error) in    
      self.nomes = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! NSArray
        print(self.nomes)
  }    
}
```

e estou recebendo essas informações:

```
[{"nome":"marcos","idade":"23","altura":"1.83"},
{"nome":"ivan","idade":"25","altura":"1.89"},
{"nome":"pedro","idade":"21","altura":"1.78"}]
```

gostaria de informar na cell da TableView "nome" no campo textLabel e "altura" como detailLabel

```
cell.textLabel!.text = nomes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("nome")
```

Answer (score 1):

O código parece correto. Talvez falte apenas forçar o tipo, usando um cast. Faça assim:

```
var temp: NSString = nomes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("nome") as NSString
cell.textlabe.text = temp
```

Se der algum erro, poste o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução melhor seria declarar um struct com esses atributos

```
struct Pessoa: Codable {
    var nome: String
    var idade: Int
    var altura: Double
}
```

E usar o JSONDecoder

```
var nomes: [Pessoa]
Alamofire.request(.GET, MyUrl,parameters: nil,encoding: .JSON).response {
    (_, _, data, error) in    
    self.nomes = try jsonDecoder.decode([Pessoa.self], from: data)
    print(self.nomes)
}
```

Daí é só fazer

```
cell.textLabel.text = nomes[indexPath.row].nome
```